# Converting an Integer into a string NOT NUMERIC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

So what I'm trying to do is convert an INTEGER type into a string from a jdbc to put in a jtextfield, unfortunately the String.OfValue cannot convert my Integer type but can for my NUMBERIC type.

**Did not use numeric because auto incrementation won't work on a numeric for some odd reason (if you know the solution to this please tell me)

HERES my string method

```
      String sql ="select * from patient where patient_id='"+Table_click+"'";
      pst =conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      rs=pst.executeQuery();
      if (rs.next()) {
         String add1 =pst.toString();
         p_id.setText(add1);
      }
```

Here is my error message

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Comparisons between 'INTEGER' and 'CHAR (UCS_BASIC)' are not supported. Types must be comparable. String types must also have matching collation. If collation does not match, a possible solution is to cast operands to force them to the default collation (e.g. SELECT tablename FROM sys.systables WHERE CAST(tablename AS VARCHAR(128)) = 'T1')

Comment: umm... it looks like you are getting the value of the "patient_id" not a value from SQL

Comment: You need to retrieve the value as an integer, as the exception explains. `String add1 = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("patient_id"));`

Comment: @Vulcan add that as an answer, it is probably the case.

Comment: What datatype is `patient_id`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly,

```
Integer patient_id = //get value of patient_id from database
String add1 =patient_id.toString();
p_id.setText(add1);
```

Comment: Ok so this is my new code

              String sql ="select * from patient where patient_id='"+Table_click+"'";
          pst =conn.prepareStatement(sql);
          rs=pst.executeQuery();
          if(rs.next()){
              
              
              
                       
             String add1 =pst.toString();
              
              p_id.setText(add1);

my error is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Comparisons between 'INTEGER' and 'CHAR (UCS_BASIC)' are not supported. ... (more but cannot insert) what do you think?

Comment: Updated above for easy viewing :)