# Why can I not convert the integer into a string?

Tags: java, user-interface, jdbc

Why won't this code work? I'm trying to autofill in my jtext fields but it won't let me select the name field if it's not a string.

I tried to convert my `p_id` to a `string` but it still doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
 int row = tablePatient.getSelectedRow();
      String Table_click=(tablePatient.getModel().getValueAt(row, 10).toString());

      String sql ="select * from patient where p_id='"+Table_click+"'";
      pst =conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      rs=pst.executeQuery();
      if(rs.next()){

String add10=rs.getString(String.valueOf("p_id"));
pat_id.setText (add10);


      }
```

** I have other add1, add2, but I choose not display it because it would be a waste of space

My error is:

> ava.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Comparisons between 'INTEGER' and
>   'CHAR (UCS_BASIC)' are not supported. Types must be comparable. String
>   types must also have matching collation. If collation does not match,
>   a possible solution is to cast operands to force them to the default
>   collation (e.g. SELECT tablename FROM sys.systables WHERE
>   CAST(tablename AS VARCHAR(128)) = 'T1')

Please help :)

Comment: 1.) in the query leave out the ' if p_id is an integer in your db table. 2.) use rs.getInt and convert to String after you have it.

Comment: Didn't you just ask this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930647/converting-an-integer-into-a-string-not-numeric

Comment: @greedybuddha looks like that, but that answer doesn't provide a real solution =\

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `PreparedStatement`s in the right way:

```
String sql ="select * from patient where p_id=?";
pst =conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(Table_click));
//in case p_id is a VARCHAR, comment above line and uncomment below line
//pst.setString(1, Table_click);
rs=pst.executeQuery();
//rest of code...
```

Also, this line is really bad:

```
String add10=rs.getString(String.valueOf("p_id"));
```

`String#valueOf` another String is like using the same String. Just use:

```
String add10=rs.getString("p_id");
```

Comment: +1 for using `PreparedStatement`

Comment: Thanks so much for that! Unfortunately parseString, doesn't work... any tips? it says ... cannot find symbol.. etc

Comment: @user1724891 my bad. Code fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `'` in your `query`

Change you `query` to

```
 String sql ="select * from patient where p_id="+Table_click;
```